# To Which Endpoint will SAML Authority send back LogoutResponse after processing a LogOutRequest received from a session participant?

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth

To which **Endpoint** will SAML session authority send back LogoutResponse after processing a LogOutRequest received from a session participant?

Answer (score 0):

[SAML Logout Profile](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) Section. 4.4.5 states the logout request and **responses** may be sent to the SingleLogoutService endpoint that's been provided in session authority's/participant's metadata file.